# jquery .remove() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, footer, removechild

I'm simply trying to remove the footer from my home page.

```
if (OBJECT.Homepage.isHomePage == true){
    jQuery('footer').remove();
}
```

It seems the .remove() is doing more of a display: none; than actually removing the node from the DOM. When I view the page source the footer still exists - and although it is not displaying the content, there is a large vertical scroll, as if the height of footer is still applying.

I thought it possibly had to do with using the footer tag instead of #footer, but when I did that I had the same results.

Comment: Does #footer have a height specified? Could you give us the code? It sounds like some element has a height defined because display:none would eliminate any height the element had.

Comment: removing an element completely removes it from the dom. Viewing the source of a page does not tell you what elements currently are or are not in the dom, it's a snapshot of what the browser returned before javascript manipulated it. More than likely your problem is a css problem and the element is being properly removed.

Comment: Yes please provide all relevant code if possible, by all accounts the remove() method should remove the element from the DOM, and has in previous experience. #footer would only accurately select if you set the id attribute of your footer tag to 'footer', for what it's worth

Comment: adding to Kevin B's comment, there are debuggers like firebug and even ie's developer tools where you can refresh the dom elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="remove footer"/>
<footer>test</footer>​
```

JS:

```
$("input").click(function(){$("footer").remove();})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9unpH/ see this demo. It works fine.

> When I view the page source the footer still exists

I guess you are usign something like right mouse click  -> View Page Source , if so - than everything is correct. It will not include changes done by JS, simply show what it gets from server (even more - browser may send another request to a server to get HTML for view source).

Try using developer tools to see changes made by JS (F12 in all browsers, in FF you may need to install firebug)

> there is a large vertical scroll, as if the height of footer is still
>   applying.

Suppose this is because of some other styles on your page, not because of `footer`

Comment: Thanks, I did notice this using Chrome's inspector. The extra vertical scrolling was a result of styling on another div. Thanks again for your help